# Как перенести большое изображение в маленький canvas, сохранив пропорции?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Изображение имеет большие размеры ширина client_width>1920 и высота client_height>1080. А canvas - 1920x1080. Как с помощью javascript функции drawimage() перенести такое изображение полностью без обрезки на такой новый холст?

```
<canvas id="img" name="img"  width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
<img id="duble_img" src="photo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)() принимает параметры dWidth и dHeight. Они отвечают за размеры изображения на canvas.

Если ваще изображение имеет такое же соотношение сторон, как и canvas

```
let img = document.getElementById("duble_img");
canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

Если соотношения сторон не совпадают, то нужно посчитать ширину или высоту, чтобы сохранить пропорции изображения

```
let img = document.getElementById("duble_img");
let ratio = img.clientWidth / img.clientHeight; //соотношение сторон img
let width = 1920;
let height = widht/ratio;
canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width , height);
```